# Two Buttons Fighting with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I've got a view that should look like this

```
 ----------------------------------
| [button 1]            [button 2] |
 ----------------------------------
```

But I'm having issues where one or the other will take over full width. I can't seem to find the right combination of compression resistance / content hugging to get what I want.

I'm using the following visual layout code:

```
H:|-(leftPadding)-[button1]-(>=middlePadding)-[button2]-(rightPadding)-|
V:|-(topPadding)-[button1]-(bottomPadding)-|
V:|-(topPadding)-[button2]-(bottomPadding)-|
```

Where the padding values are all currently 8. Also, the buttons shouldn't overlap, so second button's width should take priority over the first's.

In the app, the labels may change, so I'd like to look like:

```
 ----------------------------------
| [button 1]   [some other button] |
 ----------------------------------
```

or:

```
 ----------------------------------
| [some other button]   [button 2] |
 ----------------------------------
```

When I update the button text, do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the left button (the title may compress), leave the compression resistance and content hugging priorities at their default settings. In other words, do nothing.

For the right button (the title may not be compressed), increase its compression resistance priority. The default compression resistance priority is 750. Increasing this to 751 will suffice.

```
[button2 setContentCompressionResistancePriority:751 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

And if you were doing this in IB:

The left button (title can be compressed):
[image]

The right button (title can not be compressed):

[image]

Updated:
Constraints used to position buttons:

[image]

Comment: This got me most of the way there. I was under the assumption that I could have a `|-[one]-(>=space)-[two]-|` relationship where the buttons would size themselves to fit, but it seems that isn't the case. I added some calculate widths for the buttons and I got there.

Comment: @StephenH.Gerstacker Your assumption is correct. Your constraints were spot on. In fact, I created the same constraints as you, only in IB. The only additional thing I had to do was tweak the compression resistance priority of one of the buttons. So you shouldn't have to calculate the width of a button here. I'll post a screenshot of my constants in IB at the end of my answer above soon.

Answer (score 1):

`[targetView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` to politely request the ui to update constraints it's next run through, or `[targetView layoutIfNeeded]` to force the constraint calculations immediately. In this, the target view is your button, after you change the title. How the inner UILabel on the button is configured to behave/resize will effect results.

Try something like the following.

```
#import "ADViewController.h"

@interface ADViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *button2;
@end

@implementation ADViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.button1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.button1 setTitle:@"button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button1.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [self.button1 setTag:1];
    [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(growTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button1];

    self.button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.button2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.button2 setTitle:@"button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button2.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [self.button2 setTag:2];
    [self.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(growTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.button2];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSString *hString = @"H:|-[_button1(>=minButtonWidth)]-(>=minMiddle)-[_button2(>=minButtonWidth)]-|";
    NSString *vString1 = @"V:|-[_button1]-|";
    NSString *vString2 = @"V:|-[_button2]-|";

    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"minMiddle": @40,
                              @"minButtonWidth": @100 };
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button1,_button2);
    NSMutableArray *cons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
                            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:hString
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:metrics
                                                                      views:views]];
    [cons addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vString1
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:metrics
                                                                        views:views]];
    [cons addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vString2
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:metrics
                                                                        views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:cons];
}

- (void)growTitle:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld", button.titleLabel.text, button.tag]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

@end
```